# Zf3 populate select Element with data from Database

Tags: zend-framework3, laminas

I know this topic was discussed 2 years ago. But I stuck on difficulty that I would like to solve.

I would like to create a zf3 form which contains more than two Select Element.

I would like to populate them with data coming from different repositories (options values of each Select item come from distinct repository).

First all, I tried to pass the service manager (from where I can access to my repositories) in the constructor of my form but I heard that this solution is not suitable at all.

So how can I include multiples repositories in my form to populate my Select Elements?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer:

1. Create a class that extends the `Select`
2. Create a factory for such class
3. Add this custom element in your module configuration (`module.config.php`)
4. Use this class as `type` for your form elements
5. Retrieve the form through the form manager
6. Example, for controllers, adapt the controller's factory

### Detailed answer:

1. Create a class that extends the `Select`, like `BrandSelect`

```php
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Laminas\Form\Element\Select;

class BrandSelect extends Select {

    protected $repository;

    public function __construct($repository, $name = null, $options = []) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the element
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init() {
        $valueOptions = [];
        foreach ($this->repository->fetchBrands() as $brand) {
            $valueOptions[$brand->getBrandId()] = $brand->getName();
        }
        asort($valueOptions);
        $this->setValueOptions($valueOptions);
    }

}
```

2. Create a factory for such class

```php
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use MyModule\Db\Repository;

class BrandSelectFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, $options = null): BrandSelect {
        $repository = $container->get(Repository::class);
        return new BrandSelect($repository);
    }

}
```

3. Add this custom element in your module configuration (`module.config.php`)

```php
namespace MyModule;

return [
    // ..
    // Other configs
    // ..
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Form\Element\BrandSelect::class => Form\Element\BrandSelectFactory::class
        ]
    ]
];
```

4. Use this class as `type` for your form elements. 
   It is really important to add all elements in the `init()` method, otherwise it will not work. I also added the `InputFilterProviderInterface`.
   In this case, form doens't require any other element its constructor. If needed, you must create a factory for the form and pass all params you need. The form factory must be added in `module.config.php` configuration, always under the `form_elements` key (as did for the `BrandSelect`):

```php
namespace MyModule\Form;

use Laminas\Form\Form;
use Laminas\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BrandForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = []) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }

    // IT IS REALLY IMPORTANT TO ADD ELEMENTS IN INIT METHOD!
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'brand_id',
            'type' => Element\BrandSelect::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Brands',
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        $inputFilter[] = [
            'name' => 'brand_id',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'Int']
            ]
        ];
        return $inputFilter;
    }

}
```

5. Retrieve the form through the form manager
   Form **must** be retrieved using correct manager, which isn't the `service manager`, but the `FormElementManager`.
   For example, if you need the form inside `BrandController`:

```php
<?php

namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Laminas\Form\FormElementManager;
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Laminas\View\Model\ViewModel;

class BrandController extends AbstractActionController {

    private $formManager;

    public function __construct(FormElementManager $formManager) {
        $this->formManager = $formManager;
    }

    public function addBrandAction() {
        $form = $this->formManager->get(\MyModule\Form\BrandForm::class);

        // Do stuff

        return new ViewModel([
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }

}
```

6. Finally, you'll have to adapt the controller's factory:

```php
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class BrandControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, $options = null): BrandController {
        $formManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');
        return new BrandController($formManager);
    }

}
```

which must be configured under `controllers` key in `module.config.php`:

```php
namespace MyModule;

return [
    // ..
    // Other configs
    // ..
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\BrandController::class => Controller\BrandControllerFactory::class
        ],
    ],
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Form\Element\BrandSelect::class => Form\Element\BrandSelectFactory::class
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thank you @Ermenegildo . I will try it and keep you posted very soon.